# JavaScript 'clip-mask' equivalent on scroll (GSAP and ScrollMagic available)

Tags: javascript, css, gsap, scrollmagic

## The question

Is there a way to fade contents out on a gradient similar to `clip-mask` using JavaScript or jQuery?

## The problem

I've got a fixed header with a transparent background, and a '.png' logo with transparent pieces. I have semi-transparent elements which scroll vertically up the page, and thus below the header and logo.

When things scroll under the logo they show through and everything looks pretty bad.

### The proposed solution

We'd like to fade out content above a certain point (the bottom of the header). We're using [ScrollMagic](https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic) with [GSAP](https://greensock.com/) to animate elements as they scroll which causes conflicts with `clip-path` and other CSS fixes, so I am looking for a JavaScript/jQuery fix most likely.

[image]

### Sample code

At the request of a commenter, I've created a JSFiddle which includes a few pieces.

There are two elements that should be considered: `#masthead` and `#content`. There's an area (in `blue`) below `#masthead` in which I would like `#content` to fade as a gradient from opacity `1` to `0`.

https://jsfiddle.net/dotzak/o9hcnufe/3/

Comment: can you put together a jsFiddle or a codepen please?

Comment: Yea, no problem. I've added a sample via JSFiddle to replace the sample code.

Comment: You can't make a part of an element transparent, no.